# .net 7 Route Handling and Parameter Binding in minimal apis

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

I had asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75254523/net-regex-iterating-multiple-named-groups-in-the-same-input-string) on Regex parsing with multiple named groups. This is the original problem that motivated that question and is an orthogonal problem.

In .net 7, using [the minimal apis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/parameter-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is there a way to map multiple key-value pairs that appear in the url query parameters? The documentation in the previous link gives examples of binding a single parameter to the url fragment or slug. How do we map multiple key-value pairs?

The asp.net core documentation provides the following example:

```
app.MapGet("/{id}", (int id,
                     int page,
                     [FromHeader(Name = "X-CUSTOM-HEADER")] string customHeader,
                     Service service) => { });
```

where

- `id` is mapped to the path parameter,
- `page` is mapped to the query parameter,
- `customHeader` is mapped to a header field,
- `service` is provided by dependency injection

My Example URL is: `/o/post?id=123&filter=xyz`

Does .net 7 asp.net core provide a way to map the `id` and `filter` parameters to a handler automatically or should I use

```
app.MapGet("/o/{*rest}", (string rest) => $"Routing to {rest}");
```

and handle the parsing myself?

I am thinking there should be a simpler way than handling the parsing myself. Is there one?

Comment: Do you want multiple routes that bind to the same action?

Comment: No. This is a single route and a handler for that. The `/o/<otype>?<query_criteria>` is the general pattern of the route. In the backend, this constructs a query to a table for `<otype>` using a filter criteria derived from the `<query_criteria>`.

Comment: @vernou, coming to think of it, `/o/post?id=123&filter=xyz` and `/o/comment?id=1001` are examples of routes that get handled by the same handler. So, the answer to your question is Yes. I meant that the same handler handles the logic for all object type queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comment, yes this is easily possible with minimal APIs.
What you have to do is to pass the HttpRequest and access the query of that request.

I would do something like this.

```
app.MapGet("/{type}", (string type,
                 HttpRequest request) =>
                 {
                     return new { Type = type, queryParams = request.Query};
                 }); ;
```

if you now call your endpoint like this `/comment?userID=21546&commentID=76165` you will get this result:

```
{
    "type": "comment",
    "queryParams": [
        {
            "key": "userID",
            "value": [
                "21546"
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "commentID",
            "value": [
                "76165"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If you call this URL `/post?postID=76165` you will get this response. As you can see only the sent query parameters are available.

```
{
    "type": "post",
    "queryParams": [
        {
            "key": "postID",
            "value": [
                "76165"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can then build a switch case based on the type string and do whatever logic you need. Hope this puts you in the right direction.